# Issue in changing the circle to this shape using Geometry node, help me changing it into 4 edges shape

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

[image]I am making revealing [image]animation using Geometry node and I am currently revealing it in a circle shape but I want to reveal it in a 4 Edges shape using Geometry node, help me how to convert it

I am attaching Google drive link of my file as well: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aqpatom-RvDMzXkrsWcUzrehkRYxt5N7/view?usp=sharingenter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: normally GN questions are VERY popular here and answered in minutes. But...yours is pretty unclear. You write about "4 edges shape" but i am sorry, i don't see any 4 edge shape in your wanted pic. maybe you wanna explain that or replace your image?